# How to write a GUI function/command in gVim?

Tags: vim

I only found three types of dialog in gVim:

```
:let n = inputdialog("value for shiftwidth", &sw)
:call confirm("Save changes?", "&Yes\n&No\n&Cancel")
:browse e
```

Can I write a GUI Dialog, such as a ColorPick-Dialog to choose RGB value?
Does gVim support custom GUI widget?

Comment: Related thread: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/gui-dialogs-td1183378.html - Are you looking to make textual menus, or menus more native to the OS gVim is running on?

Comment: there is at least another dialog: `:set guifont=*`

Comment: @Benoit - There is also the one asking you whether you want to save the changes, but in general, the answer to his question is - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

However you can make up your own DLL and `libcall()`. If your library must return a string (pointer to a zero-terminated array of characters) it will leak.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe gVim support any custom "GUI" widgets, but you can always use an external program that shows that dialog and writes the output to `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Vim (in general) does not support any GUI boxes. However, if you wish to extend Vim, it is open source, so all you have to do is go to [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org), download the source and hack. Though, it will probably take a bit more effort to accomplish what you want than just three lines.